# how h can true join in examples?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, outer-join, self-join

I have the following query which does not give the expected result:

```
SELECT "invoice"."ITEMNO", 
  "invoice"."Outgoing", 
  "storeage"."incoming" 
FROM   "MVXJDTAP"."MVXJDTA"."invoice" 
INNER JOIN "MVXJDTAP"."MVXJDTA"."storeage " 
  ON "invoice"."ITEMNO" = "storeage"."itemno"
ORDER BY"storeage"."itemno"

Tables:
invoice
itemno       Outgoing
ZOMV3-94        4 
ZOMV3-94        7 

storeage
itemno      incoming
ZOMV3-94    3
ZOMV3-94    1
ZOMV3-94    60
ZOMV3-94    5
```

The query gives the result:

```
itemno      outgoing      incoming
ZOMV3-94       4             3
ZOMV3-94       4             1
ZOMV3-94       4             60
ZOMV3-94       4             5
ZOMV3-94       7             3
ZOMV3-94       7             1 
ZOMV3-94       7             60
ZOMV3-94       7             5
```

But I want to get the following TRUE result:

```
ZOMV3-94       4           NULL OR 0
ZOMV3-94       7           NULL OR 0
ZOMV3-94     NULL OR 0       3
ZOMV3-94     NULL OR 0       1
ZOMV3-94     NULL OR 0       60
ZOMV3-94     NULL OR 0       5
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: Why are you "putting" "all" "of" "your" "table" "and" "column" "names" "in" "quotes"? There doesn't seem to be a good reason for it - unless your intent is to make your code extremely difficult to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `UNION ALL` instead of a `JOIN` to get the result:

```
select itemno,
  outgoing,
  null as incoming
from invoice
union all
select itemno,
  null,
  incoming
from storeage;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33d64/1). This gives a result:

```
|   ITEMNO | OUTGOING | INCOMING |
----------------------------------
| ZOMV3-94 |        4 |   (null) |
| ZOMV3-94 |        7 |   (null) |
| ZOMV3-94 |   (null) |        3 |
| ZOMV3-94 |   (null) |        1 |
| ZOMV3-94 |   (null) |       60 |
| ZOMV3-94 |   (null) |        5 |
```

Comment: This is the same route I'd use

Comment: THANKS BUT WHEN I JOIN TABEL 3

Comment: I CAN'T ADD ANOTHER TABLE (PRODUCT DT.) SO ADD DISCRIBTION CULOMN

Comment: @BelalIt Please post a new question with the details on adding a new table.

Comment: I WANT USE ANOTHER TABLE ZOMV3-94     4      ZOOM LKY

Comment: WHEN I PRESS ask q show me "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more."how can i do ?